# C# MySQL connection multiple select statements

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, select

I can connect to MySQL database from my WinForms app fine. The question is once I am logged in how can I perform multiple select statements without having to login again?

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
connection.Open();

MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
MySqlDataReader Reader;

command.CommandText = "select id from user ";
```

Then I want to perform a select statement for another table without having to create connection again.
How do I dothis?
I can't seem to just do `connection.CreateCommand`.

Comment: Well, you can use the same connection object again for a different query

Comment: show your full code for help you.

Comment: Check think post once http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/201603/Is-any-possible-Multiple-query-executing-in-single.aspx#answer1

Comment: yes as @rahul told you can open connection globaly in your project and run the other query for other table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the queries are within the same block, you can use the same connection..  However, once closed, you need to re-open it.

```
using( YourConnectionObject )
{
   ... open connection ...
   ... create your sql querying object... and command 
   SQLCommand.Connection = YourConnectionObject;

   Execute your Query

   SQLCommand.CommandText = "a new sql-select statement";

   Execute your NEW query while connection still open/active

   SQLCommand.CommandText = "a third sql-select statement";

   Execute your THIRD query while connection still open/active

   ... close your connection
}
```

However, in your application, you can have a single "connection" object like at the application level, or at a form level with the necessary login / connection settings stuff.  Then, internally to each form, you can

```
Open
Run Query
Run Query
Run Query
Close
```

as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using a `DataReader`. You can only have 1 `DataReader` open at a time per connection. `using` blocks come in handy for those:

```
using( var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader() ) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        // get values, do stuff
    }
}// reader gets closed
```

You only hint at it in the code in your question (currently), but it's possible that is part of your problem. You haven't shown how you're using the `DataReader`, so I'm not certain. Just a possibility.